# How does a large number of KnownTypes affect perfromance of the DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, performance, inheritance

Can anyone provide any insight on how the number of possible KnownTypes on a datacontract in an inheritance chain might affect the performance of the WCF `DataContractSerializer`?

Consider:

```
[ServiceContract]
BaseClass GetInfo()

[KnownType=Typeof(Class1)]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass

[DataContract]
public class Class1 : BaseClass
```

Here I only have only one derived class (and thus one knownType). Now, suppose I have not one but but 10, 100, or 1000... classes.

In know thousands of derived classes is a bit :) exaggerated but how would this affect the performance of the `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: So you are done with all the other possible performance bottlenecks in your codebase?

Comment: @rene: What's the reason to ask that?

Comment: @abatishchev I'm trying to verify if the OP is not optimizing too early

Comment: @rene: any bottleneck which can be identified before writing code means saving time in a project. This is why I ask if anyone has experience with this. To me this looks like a good pattern: perform same function on same interface on get 100 different classes...

Comment: Your comment adds a twist to your original question. I interpreted performance as something in milliseconds, it looks like your more interested in validation of the design, aka architecture, design or programmability 'performance'. I agree that if you don't write code you save money. I have been called to projects once to often where no code was written by 15 software engineers in a month. As code is f*&^%ing hard to get it right, just start, try, make mistakes and keep refactoring rates as high as possible. I'm sure your pattern and some unexpected patterns would have evolved over time.

Comment: @rene: actually I was talking about milliseconds but had to explain why I was doing this. All I wanted to know is how inheritance affects DataContractSerializer performance. I could implement a test app however

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in Measuring performance of any code construct I highly recommend the msdn articles of Vance Morrison on [Measure IT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx). Highly eductional. I've used Measure It a few times myself to get the grasp on perfomance issues.

For overall process performance have a look at [PerfView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2011/12/28/publication-of-the-perfview-performance-analysis-tool.aspx)